# How can I make Blazegraph and SWRL work together?

Tags: owl, swrl, blazegraph

I have written an SWRL rule in an [ontology](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuel-peers/campyDatabase/master/Ontologies/CampyOntology2.0.owl) I've written. Specifically, the rule is:

```
hasSampleLocale(?i, tag_retail) -> hasSampleLocale(?i, tag_domestic)
```

This works just fine and dandy when I test it in Protege with the Hermit reasoner, but alas it does not work when I test it in Blazegraph. I have read [here](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/InferenceAndTruthMaintenance) that Blazegraph can use rules, but I'd like to get SWRL working with Blazegraph. Is it possible?

Comment: There's no mention of SWRL support on their website.

Comment: Is SPARQL and option?  If so, the SWRL rule can be written and executed using SPARQL.

Comment: Then wouldn't the SPARQL query have to be triggered every time someone inputs the triple `:someInstance :hasSampleLocale :tag_retail` ?